# How to do unit testing in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I am trying to learn scala (and also the concept of unit testing).

I have an object

```
object Foo{
          def parse(s:String): Array[String] = {
              return s.split(",")
           }

       }
```

A very simple code block.. but now I want to write unit test?

My code structure is:

```
src/main/scala/foo.scala
   src/test/scala/(empty)
```

I am using sbt to compile and run?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this in `src/test/scala/FooSpec.scala`

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class FooSpec extends Specification {
  "Foo" should {
    "parse a String" in {
      Foo.parse("a,b") == Array("a","b")      
    }
  }
}
```

then in the sbt prompt you can run `test`

for this to work you will need to add a dependency on specs 2 in your build.sbt [as explained in the documentation](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/#Dependencies)

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.11" % "test"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a very big topic.

I'm a proponent of Specs2 along with its Mockito and ScalaCheck support. All of these have good documentation, so I recommend you start by looking them up on the Web.

Comment: How do I use the frameworks you mentioned to test above piece of code

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the Specs2 site. I recommend you look them over and start constructing tests.